# Visual Studio 2017, 1 workspace per TFVC project or multiple TFVC projects within 1 workspace?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

I am a bit confused about the concept of workspace and working folders. I see in the Source Control Explorer I can setup multiple workspaces on my machine. My understanding of workspace is basically a folder that contains all of my projects (even unrelated ones). For example, C:\Projects

I currently have a single workspace that is called the name of my computer which points to a directory called C:\Projects that has several projects in it that are each their own project on visual studio online. For example: DESKTOP-43DDV90P has a working folder for each project inside of it.

```
WORKSPACE: DESKTOP-43DDV90P
Source Control Folder: $/Project1, Local Folder C:\Projects\Project1
Source Control Folder: $/Project2, Local Folder C:\Projects\Project2
```

I would like to know if this is a correct assumption OR if I should be creating a workspace per project like the following:

```
WORKSPACE: PROJECT1-WS
Source Control Folder: $/Project1, Local Folder C:\Projects\Project1
WORKSPACE: PROJECT2-WS
Source Control Folder: $/Project2, Local Folder C:\Projects\Project2
```

When I finish setting everything up with a new ASP.NET Core web application under source control my directory structure looks like the following:

```
C:\Projects\Project 1
this contains:
Project1 (folder vs creates for solution)
BuildProcessTemplates (folder from vs online)

C:\Projects\Project 1\Project1
this folder contains:
Project1 vs solution file
Project1 (folder that finally takes you to the project1 site files)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TFS workspace is basically an account between your computer and the TFS server.  It contains a set of `ServerPath -> Local Path` mappings, and some settings about how the workspace is maintained (e.g. permissions, file timestamp behavior, etc).

Often when working on a project you'll end up creating branches.  This is when workspace mappings become relevant.  If you don't have branches, then you'll usually just want to map the entire codebase - i.e. you want all of the sources.  But when you *do* have branches, often you'll want only one branch at a time.  For example, if I have this:

[image: Sample repository with Master and FeatureX branches]

You can see how each branch contains the same set of files.  If I'm developing something in the FeatureX branch, eventually I will merge it into the Master branch.

This is when your question becomes most relevant: do I have a workspace that contains both of these, or do I have separate workspaces for each branch?  This is a matter of preference.  I prefer to have separate workspaces, because it avoids the case where I've made changes in multiple branches and only want to check in changes to one of them.  For example:

[image: Showing changes across multiple branches]

I might not notice in a larger project that I have modified files from two different branches.  TFS does allow this, but usually when I'm working in one branch I don't want to affect another one.  Another issue that can occur is that TFS sometimes has issues when merging changes if one of the included changesets spans multiple branches.  For example, say I check in the pictured change; then I create a new branch (Feature2); then I merge the changeset into Feature2.  What should happen?  Does it take the copy that I checked into Master or into FeatureX?  You can make this work, but the point is that you can also fall into some weird situations.  With multiple workspaces, I would only ever see changes for the branch pertaining to that workspace:

[image: Sample workspace mapping for FeatureX branch only]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I finish mapping a working folder as a project the directory structure looks like this. C:\Projects\Project1... this folder has BuildProcessTemplates and Project1 folders in it. Then if you click into Project1 within here you get the folder with the VS solution in it, then finally if you click into Project1 again it takes you into the projects files. This is for a solution with an ASP.NET Core web project in it. Does it make sense? I just feel like there is an extra folder on the outside but I guess this might make sense.

Comment: Also, can you give me an idea of what order you do things. I have been creating a new project on visual studio online first, then setting up the server -> local mapping for that project in the workspace, then making sure I am connected to the proper team project, then finally clicking new solution at the bottom of the team explorer window to add a new asp.net core project, but when adding I do not check Add to Source Control. Once project is created I right click solution and add to source control. Does this seem right?

Comment: @BlakeRivell I've updated my answer to show a trivial project with branches.  This is normally what I would expect to see.  The BuildProcessTemplates are added by TFS automatically, then you have a folder for your branches, then inside that you have your solution, projects, in whatever folder structure you prefer.

Comment: @BlakeRivell as to the order, again, it's a preference.  If you do check the Add To Source Control box, it will add them according to the current workspace mapping, based on the local path.  If that's not mapped, it should prompt you to add a new mapping.  The main thing to remember is to create a folder for your first branch, and put your project inside of that.

Answer (score 2):

That’s depending on your situation, company policy etc… It’s hard to manage if there are too many mapping in a workspace, if not, a workspace is ok.

Some articles about optimize that can help you:

## [Using multiple workspaces with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2013/05/30/using-multiple-workspaces-with-visual-studio/)

## [Optimize your workspace](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/optimize-your-workspace)